# ASP.NET MVC Getting items added to a list via Javascript to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a ListBoxFor in my html page:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedProduct, new SelectList(Model.Products, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control col-12", @id = "produtosEnvolvidos" })
```

and I want to enable the user to add items to that list through a plus(+) button

```
<button type="button" id="addList" class="btn ml-2">+</button>
```

I'm currently adding items to the list via javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addList").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("produtosEnvolvidos");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = document.getElementById("produtotxt").value;
        x.add(option);
    })
});
```

and once the user submits the form I want to retrieve all the newly added items in my controller so I can update the database, but once I check the Model.Products list it's always empty, I think because the javascript doesn't actually talk to asp.net correctly.

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Product")]
public string SelectedProduct { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Products { get; set; }
```

Inside Create GET:

```
model.Products = new SelectList(model._Products, "Product", "Text");
```

Is there any solution to this?

I can use technologies like JQuery and Ajax.

Comment: MVC form submission works based on the `name` property, not the `id`.

Comment: @Dwight What kind of model are you using in the View? Does the Model hold a List<T> called Products? (I'm assuming).

Comment: You have to have a control with the same name as your model is expecting so that it can fill it.

Comment: The Model.Products is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so I've changed the Name to match the same as on the Model `Products` but it still returns null when inside the controller.

Comment: I'm only being able to get the SelectedItem

Comment: Where is the data being sent? I don't see any razor `URL.Action()` or jquery `$post()` transmitting the data back to the server. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I've ommited the code for better visualization, it's inside a Html.BeginForm

Comment: You are setting only the text of your drop-down, you also need to set the value attribute

Comment: How so? Could you please show some code?